# use jq to replace cloud formation parameter value

Tags: aws-cloudformation, jq

I am trying to replace project ParameterKey:Project with ParameterValue:test in the below Cloudformation parameters file

```
    [{
  "ParameterKey": "Project",
  "ParameterValue": "<changeMe>"
 }, 
 {
  "ParameterKey": "DockerInstanceType",
  "ParameterValue": "m3.medium"
}]
```

I am trying to execute below jq command

```
cat config.json |              
  jq "map(if .ParameterKey == "Project"
          then . + {\"ParameterValue\":\"test\"}
          else .
          end)" > populated_config.json
```

I am getting the below error

```
jq: error: Project/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
map(if .ParameterKey == Project                        
jq: 1 compile error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're prematurely closing the string passed to `jq` by not escaping the quotes for "Project" in the equality.

You can simplify by enclosing the expression with single quotes, and no escaping is necessary:

```
$ cat config.json | jq 'map(if .ParameterKey == "Project" then . + {"ParameterValue":"test"} else . end)'
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Project",
    "ParameterValue": "test"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "DockerInstanceType",
    "ParameterValue": "m3.medium"
  }
]
```